# Anyone know an eloquent way to make a constructor constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, constructor

I'm trying to tackle this from the command line: Is there an elegant way to use a constructor to create constructors with parameters named via arguments provided to the first constructor?
Let's say we want a constructor for groupings of animals. The grouping constructor takes arguments that name any parameters the new constructor will take. The new constructor is named with a variable assignment. Then in the new constructor we can set those parameters as properties on an object (previously named with our variable assignment). I would expect that functionality to look a little something like this:

```
var herd = new grouping("species", "color", "cattle");
var school = new grouping("species", "color", "dolphins");
console.log(new herd(20, "Angus", "black"));
herd({
  cattle: 20,
  species: "Angus",
  color: "black"
})
console.log(new school(2, "Bottlenose", "grey"))
school({
  dolphins: 2,
  species: "Bottlenose",
  color: "grey"
})
```

In the searching I've done on "constructor constructors", "dynamic function name assignment", and "dynamic javascript constructor", it seems to me this is unavoidably messy. If so, does that makes this an instance to forget DRY?

Comment: Why not use a single object as the parameter?

Comment: What's the real-life use case of this?

Comment: @Michal I'm writing an sms interfacing app that uses node-json-db; I'm using JSON files as a db. The classes I've been writing share logic--in their defaults, methods, and constructors--that is necessitated by my use of a JSON db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do what you want. Note that you don't have to call this with `new` since we don't needs "instances" of those functions:

```js
function grouping(...keys) {
  return function (...values) {
    return keys.reduce((obj, key, i) => (obj[key] = values[i], obj), {});
  }
}

var herd = grouping("species", "color", "cattle");
console.log(herd(20, "Angus", "black"));
```

But if you are doing this instead of directly using object literals, only to not repeat the key names, reconsider your decision. Without looking at the calls that created `herd` or `school`, you don't know in which order the arguments to pass.
It seems that simply using object literals would be more maintainable:

```
var obj = {
  cattle: 20,
  species: "Angus",
  color: "black"
};
```

If you really want a constructor generator (which only makes sense if you make use of the prototype), then you can do this instead:

```js
function grouping(...keys) {
  return function (...values) {
    keys.forEach((key, i) => this[key] = values[i]);
  }
}

var Herd = grouping("species", "color", "cattle");
console.log(new Herd(20, "Angus", "black"));
```